# ClosedXML creating an existing workbook using path gives exception

Tags: c#, winforms, closedxml

I am using ClosedXML in a Windows Forms application to open and read an Excel file.

```
if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog(this) == DialogResult.OK)
{
   
  string path = openFileDialog1.InitialDirectory + openFileDialog1.FileName;
  dt = ImportInDataTable(path, wrksheet);
  datagridReview.DataSource = dt;
                
}
```

"path" is used like this:

```
XLWorkbook workbook = new XLWorkbook(path);
```

The path variable contents looks like this:

```
"C:\\Projects\\test.xlsx"
```

Once I try to set the workbook object with path, I get an exception "System.FormatException: The text value is not a valid enumeration value"

This code was working as written earlier today. I don't understand what this exception means.

Any help is appreciated.
Ryan

EDIT 1 - add stack trace

```
   *at DocumentFormat.OpenXml.EnumValue`1.GetEnumValue(String stringVal)
   at DocumentFormat.OpenXml.EnumValue`1.Parse()
   at DocumentFormat.OpenXml.EnumValue`1.get_Value()
   at ClosedXML.Excel.XLWorkbook.LoadAutoFilterColumns(AutoFilter af, XLAutoFilter autoFilter)
   at ClosedXML.Excel.XLWorkbook.LoadAutoFilter(AutoFilter af, XLWorksheet ws)
   at ClosedXML.Excel.XLWorkbook.LoadSpreadsheetDocument(SpreadsheetDocument dSpreadsheet)
   at ClosedXML.Excel.XLWorkbook.LoadSheets(String fileName)
   at ClosedXML.Excel.XLWorkbook..ctor(String file)
   at PTSImport.Import.ImportInDataTable(String path, Int32 wrksheet) in C:\Repos\PTS\Importer\PTS-Importer\PTSImport\Import.cs:line 309
   at PTSImport.Import.buttonOpenFile_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in C:\Repos\PTS\Importer\PTS-Importer\PTSImport\Import.cs:line 46
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnClick(EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs mevent)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseUp(Message& m, MouseButtons button, Int32 clicks)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ButtonBase.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Button.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
   at System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessageW(MSG& msg)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ComponentManager.System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.IMsoComponentManager.FPushMessageLoop(IntPtr dwComponentID, Int32 reason, Int32 pvLoopData)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoopInner(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoop(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.Run(Form mainForm)
   at PTSImport.Program.Main() in C:\Repos\PTS\Importer\PTS-Importer\PTSImport\Program.cs:line 19*
```

EDIT:
I reverted back to MS Excel Interop objects since I was on a time crunch

Comment: Please add the full stack trace to your question.

Comment: Francois Botha - i added the stack trace